# Safe way handle a link submitted by user - Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection

On the site - I let users (logged in by facebook) post links on my site.

The links is run through REGEX for only allowing country specific domains/urls

Then i run curl on the submitted link/site 
for grabbing : title / image / description (og:image / og:description +++ others) 
AND 
to eliminate 404 postings.
I check for the users IP and if there is a proxy between - which is presented to the user.

I do str_replace to eliminate "<" and ">".

If this all checks out good, the data is submitted in MySQL db and posted on the users facebook.
This is off course some sort of security.

I run mysql_real_escape_string to protect against sql injection, but what about protection against malicious code which could potential be running through the server, and since i don't feel that i know enough about this i worry about it.

So what can I do in relation to safety for user input besides what i have done.

Comment: Well `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "url", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);` should be step 1 ..

Comment: If you are getting this URL via curl you will get a response of the remote server. Not sure how you are gabbing title etc. But if you are simply parsing the response no malicious code will run on your server.

Comment: fsw >> User inputs link.. -> My server grabs data from the link(site) with curl.

Comment: user1190992 >> Allrighty :-)